# Manually rotate 3D-object's local UP-axis toward World's UP-axis?

Tags: 3d, rotation, quaternions, godot, gdscript

My object can have any(unknown) rotation in the world.

I need to interpolate this object's local UP-axis, towards the World's UP-axis, without touching the object's other local rotations (imagine a buoy righting itself after a wave-hit).

But, I only manage to interpolate all the object's axis' towards all the World's axis' at the same time, effectively aligning my object to the World, like a hard drilled North Korean parade soldier.

I'm using this code to accomplish my failure:

```
var TopQuat:Quat = Quat(0,0,0,1)
transform.basis = Basis(Quat(transform.basis).slerp(TopQuat,delta))
```

Any hints for isolating this interpolation to my object's local UP-axis?

Answer (score 1):

Quaternion [SLERP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slerp#Quaternion_Slerp) will interpolate between the two orientation quaternions - i.e., when the interpolation weight reaches 1.0, your object's frame will match the world frame.

What you are looking for is a quaternion that represents axis-angle rotation between the two UP vectors. This can be computed using a [cross-product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) of the two vectors to compute the axis of rotation, [dot-product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) to compute (the cosine of) the angle between the two vectors and the [formula to create a quaternion of an axis and an angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axis%E2%80%93angle_representation#Unit_quaternions).

Depending on which framework you are using for your implementation, you might have a method like this already implemented on the quaternion class. For example, OpenEXR's `Imath::Quaternion` class includes a [`setRotation()` method](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/free-image/+/71163caf89862f79f6419077cf6f0b18b7725d52/Source/OpenEXR/Imath/ImathQuat.h#145), implementing a slightly more advanced version of the algorithm described above.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, that looks to be perfect.
However, I suddenly got busy with other things, and will test it out at some later date, and then accept, if it answers my question.